# What is a "Thank you" (categorisation of)

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Could someone advise me please what kind of word/phrase is "thank you" or a "thank you" if you prefer. For example in this sample letter what sort of phrase is "thank you"?

> Dear Sir,
>
> What price are your bacon bits by the kilogram bag please?
>
> Thank you for your time in this matter.
>
> yours sincerely,
> Curly
> CEO Proper Pork "Building a future for pork!"

Further, is it a signature, greeting or tagline?

NB: Wasn't sure how to tag this, any edits for this appreciated.

Comment: i think you waste your time to read this document that's why he/she said thanks? :p

Comment: @JavaD, I'm not sure what point you're trying to make.

Comment: it means you read my application that's why thanking for you...

Comment: @JavaD, I don't believe we've met before so not sure what you mean by your application. My apologies, I'm very confused by your comments.

Comment: ohh..I am talking about the application or letter which you posted.. so writer of this letter thanking everyone who reading this letter..? understand?

Comment: OK, I think I'm with you now.

Comment: it means understood?

Answer (score 2):

Well *thank you* is actually a contraction of *Subject + thank you*, which means it's used instead of phrases like "I thank you" or "We thank you".

I wouldn't say thank you is a greeting, and in your letter, nor is it part of the signature line. It's a sentence like any other in your letter :)

Hope that clears your question.

Answer (score 2):

"Thank you for your time" essentially means, **"Your response is greatly appreciated."**

-- Edit to address OP's question --

That's called the **complimentary closing,** I believe.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However I wasn't asking for a translation of the phrase but for a categorisation of it.

Comment: Oh, sorry - misunderstood. You mean the name of that part of the letter, correct? 

It's the complimentary closing.

Comment: Isn't the "yours" the complimentary closing? Whilst my question is not limited to the example shown, in the example shown I deliberately put "yours" between the "thank you" and the signature for this kind of reason. I'm going to edit it to "yours sincerely" to improve this distinction. Thank you again, I had not known the term "complimentary closing" before this time.

Comment: Nope, "Yours" is part of the signature block. :) Sort of like "Dear So-and-So" is the salutation, not part of the letterhead. Informal letters might squash it together, but technically it's it's own part.

Comment: Even the most informal letters usually  don't just sort of stop and jump straight to "Love, Junior" - there's a final bit like "Catch you later" or "Call me" or "Don't be a stranger" - and usually it's either last or it gets it's  own line between the "body" text and the "X O X O X O"'s. :D

Comment: The source I used disagrees? http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/complimentary+close

Comment: "Yours *sincerely*" is normally used when you have addressed the letter to a person *by name*. When addressing as "Dear Sir" and similar forms, it's more normal to use "Yours faithfully" (UK) or "Yours truly" (US).

Comment: The source I used says it's optional, and can be included in the signature or skipped depending on the formality of the letter. It seems like it depends on whether or not it's been spaced out separately... from http://bit.ly/t2s18Q and http://bit.ly/19pXri8